# Assert expected DB values without knowing insertion order in H2 database

Tags: java, spring, dbunit

I insert 2 rows in my database during my DBUnit test. I cannot predict in advance the insertion order.

My expected-db.xml file contains something along these lines :

```
<dataset>
   <files file_id="1" file_name="name1" ... />
   <files file_id="2" file_name="name2" ... />
</dataset>
```

My test fails when the file named "name2" is inserted first.

I have tried to exclude the ID column with a column filter.
I tried setting the NAME column as a the primary key but was not successful in doing so.

Knowing that the file_name value is unique. Is there a way I can assert the expected values whether the actual order respects my expected database or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the NON_STRICT_UNORDERED assertion mode

@ExpectedDatabase(value = "expected-db.xml", assertionMode = DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT_UNORDERED)

and deleted the "file_id" columns in the expected-db.xml file